# Error realloc with Dynamic Array of Void Pointers

Tags: c, dynamic, stack, realloc

I'm trying to create a dynamic set abstract data type, based on a dynamic array. However, I get a compiler  an error when an array is full and I invoke the realloc, which are: realloc(): invalid next size
My code is as follows:

```
struct arraystack{
    int top;
    int capacity;
    void **array;
    size_t data_size; //size of my data type
};

struct arraystack * createStack(int capacity,size_t size_data_type){
    struct arraystack *stack= (struct arraystack*) malloc(sizeof(struct arraystack));
    stack->capacity=capacity;
    stack->top=-1;
    stack->data_size=size_data_type;
    stack->array= malloc(stack->capacity*size_data_type);
    return stack;  
}

void push(struct arraystack *stack, void* data){
     if(isFull(stack)){
         printf("Invoco realloc\n");
         stack->capacity=(stack->capacity*2)+1;
         void **tmp=realloc(stack->array,(stack->capacity*stack->data_size)); //this line gives me an error
         if(!tmp){
             printf("Attenzione memoria insufficente!\n");
             exit(1);
         }
         stack->array=tmp;
     }
     stack->array[++stack->top]=data;
     printf("%d pushed to stack\n", data); 
}

int isFull(struct arraystack *stack){
    return stack->top == stack->capacity - 1; 
}

int main(){
    struct arraystack *tmp=createStack(5,sizeof(int));

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=20;i++){
        push(tmp,i);
        printf("top-> %d memoria allocata->%d\n",tmp->top,tmp->capacity);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the `isFull()` function and how you use this functions? Also `printf("%d pushed to stack\n", data);` should give you a warning `wrong format specifier`.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]. With these errors the heap is often overwritten by other code, so you should post a simple way to reproduce it (including all functions you're calling like @mch wrote).

Comment: `struct arraystack *tmp=createStack(5,sizeof(int));` should be `struct arraystack *tmp=createStack(5,sizeof(void*));`

Comment: sorry it was a typo now is correct!!

Comment: I dunno, @mch. Instead, I think `createStack()` should be doing `stack->array= malloc(stack->capacity * sizeof(void *));`.  That way the `data_size` member of `struct arraystack` *might* be useful for something.

Comment: doing as you said it works, but doing so will work for all possible cases (char long etc) ??
NB this is only a main test I am trying to develop a generic library @mch

Comment: Since you are allocating the array to hold actual structs (capacity x data_size), `stack->array[++stack->top]=data;` should likely be `stack->top++; memcpy(stack->array + (stack->top * stack->data_size), data, stack->data_size`), and of course you need to check whether `isFull` is `true` BEFORE writing. You also need to pass the pointer to the data when calling, i.e. `push(tmp,i);`, because `void*` parameter can only hold a pointer (usually a single `int` and that's about it, so test your code using an actual struct).

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you need `void**` or `void*`.

This line is problematic: `stack->array= malloc(stack->capacity*size_data_type);`

You never initialize this memory area correctly. It should allocate room for as many `void*` as you have objects. This has nothing to do with the data size of the pointed-at items. Each such pointer needs to be initialized. You need to keep track of the total number of pointers as well as the size of each pointed-at item.

Alternatively you should drop `void**` in favour of `void*`, if this is meant to point at a one-dimensional array or single object.

`stack->array[++stack->top]=data;` looks fishy, this leaves index 0 uninitialized.

Make sure to include `stdlib.h` or you will get severe bugs on stone age C90 compilers, bugs that your casts hide.